# Random number generator causes unit test to fail

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I am learning unit testing and I can't understand why when I debug and step through my following unit test, it passes but when I run the test it fails. My unit test is as follows:

```
[TestMethod]
        public void NewGamesHaveDifferentTargetsTothePreviousGame()
        {
            /* NOTE : At this point we need to add a random number generator 
             * to provide the digits for the hidden digits.  Using a random number 
             * generator will help ensure that different games have different 
             * hidden digits.
             * */
            //Arrange
            var theGame = new GuessingGame();

            //Act
            List<int> firstDigits = new List<int>(theGame.Target);
            theGame.NewGame();
            List<int> secondDigits = new List<int>(theGame.Target);
            theGame.NewGame();
            List<int> thirdDigits = new List<int>(theGame.Target);

            //Assert
            /* NOTE : this CollectionAssert.AreNotEqual is true even if the two 
             * collections have the same elements as long as they are in a 
             * different order.  
             * */
            CollectionAssert.AreNotEqual(firstDigits, secondDigits);
            CollectionAssert.AreNotEqual(secondDigits, thirdDigits);
        }
```

My class is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Prigmore2013_01.Models
{
    public class GuessingGame
    {
        public GuessingGame()
        {
            this.Guesses = new List<Guess>();
            this.Target = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
        }
        public List<int> Target { get; set; }
        public List<Guess> Guesses { get; set; }
       ...
        public void NewGame()
        {
            this.Target.Clear();
            var count = 4;
            var random = new Random();
            for (var i = 1; i < count; i++)
            {
                var swap = random.Next(1, 9);

                if (!this.Target.Contains(swap))
                {
                    this.Target.Add(swap);
                }
            }
        }
        ...
}
```

When I debug I can see that my random number generator is called in my test using `theGame.newGame()` and thus creates random numbers in my list. However, when I run the test, I fail the test because:
`CollectionAssert.AreNotEqual(secondDigits, thirdDigits)`; contain the same elements. Would some be able to explain to me that why when I debug it passes the test, but when I run it normally the `secondDigit`s and `thirdDigits` contain the same elements and how I can fix this?

Comment: Either use a mock/fake random number generator or use a fixed seed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely the problem is that it executes so quickly that the `Random` constructor seeds the random number generator with the same value multiple times, thereby giving you the same sequence of random numbers.

Change your code so that you initialize the random number generator in the constructor, and use the same instance in all calls to `NewGame()`.

For example:

```
public class GuessingGame
{
    private Random _random;

    public GuessingGame()
    {
        this.Guesses = new List<Guess>();
        this.Target = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
        this._random = new Random();
    }
    public List<int> Target { get; set; }
    public List<Guess> Guesses { get; set; }
   ...
    public void NewGame()
    {
        this.Target.Clear();
        var count = 4;
        for (var i = 1; i < count; i++)
        {
            var swap = _random.Next(1, 9);

            if (!this.Target.Contains(swap))
            {
                this.Target.Add(swap);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try moving your `random` variable out of the method, to the class level. Creating a new instance of Random with no seed, and in quick succession (when you're not stepping through the code) may be causing your generated values to all be the same.

```
public class GuessingGame
{
    Random random;

    public GuessingGame()
    {
        random = new Random();

        this.Guesses = new List<Guess>();
        this.Target = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
    }

    ...
```

Comment: Thank you, this works, unfortunately Jim Mischel beat you to it!